# Armadillo functionality in c#

Tags: c#, .net, lapack

Is there a way to use `Armadillo's` "C++ linear algebra library" code which has lapack  in a `C#` project?

Could you please post a simple example...

I was thinking to get a `.dll` and import it to `C#` project, is this feasible or is there another way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [PInvoke feature of .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (platform invoke) to call code in native DLLs from your managed code.

Depending on the nature of the entry points in your native DLL you might consider adding your own wrapping layer which uses more PInvoke-friendly data types.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, as Armadillo is a C++ template library -- ie. the code is not compiled into a shared library / DLL. Template code is only available at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the source?  If so can you compile it in managed C++? If it's just mathematical functions I can't see it being a huge job to do that.

Once you've done that it's a managed assembly like any other - the source language is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, https://github.com/mrbm2007/DotNumerics

I used DotNumerics and add some code to use armadillo for eigen value, solve linear equation and ...